# Unexpected results when comparing document.URL

Tags: javascript

```
if(document.URL!="location.php?img_url="+img_url){
        window.location.href = "location.php?img_url="+img_url;
    }
```

This keeps reloading the page. I check the url to see if it changes, it doesnt.

Comment: I assure you the JavaScript `!=` operator is working correctly.

Comment: Removed the ridiculous question title and unrelated tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!=` always works right. It's you who is working wrong!

In this case, the problem is that you are expecting `document.URL` to be the string that you're setting `window.location.href` to. It may well not be.

Indeed, it will never be `"location.php?img_url="+img_url`. It will always be the *complete* URL, so something like `http://www.example.com/location.php?img_url="+img_url`.

Answer (score 7):

Because look what `document.URL` is!

```
console.log(document.URL);
```

It returns the full url. `http://example.com/location.php?img_url=1234`

You are looking for an exact match, not a partial match.

One solution is to use `indexOf()`

```
if(document.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf("location.php?img_url="+img_url)===-1){
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if(window.location != "http://www.urlhere.com/location.php?img_url="+img_url){
    window.location.href = "http://www.urlhere.com/location.php?img_url="+img_url;
}
```

Comment: Just edited the answer. I meant to also include the full URL path. I just know that `window.location` is easier than `document.URL`

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.location.pathname + document.location.search` instead of `document.URL`

Comment: That won't include the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
window.location.pathname
```

instead of using

```
document.URL
```

Comment: That won't include the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot the domain name.

TRy something like this:

```
if(document.URL!="http://localhost/location.php?img_url="+img_url){
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/location.php?img_url="+img_url;
}
```